# Is it possible to update all cells in a Column that meet a criteria when a data validation list is updated?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet where I track visitors to a location. I want each instance where the visitor name is input in column B, to auto populate the name of the location in the adjacent cell in column A. The location name I want is in a data validation list (Cell I2). If I change the site name via data validation, I want it to update the location name in all cells of column A where visitor names are in column B. Currently, I can only get the first row to add the location name, and I cannot get it to change when I change the value in the data validation cell.

My current code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyDataRng As Range
Set MyDataRng = Range("B:B")
If Intersect(Target, MyDataRng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next

If Target = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 3) = ""
    End If
          
If Target <> "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 3) = Now
    End If
    
If Target = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 4) = ""
    End If
    
If Target = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = ""
    End If
    
If Target = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = ""
    End If
    
If Target = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 5) = ""
    End If
    
If Target = "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = ""
    End If
    
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Target <> "" Then
    Target.Offset(0, -1) = Target.Cells(0, 8)
    
    
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not sure how to get each row to add the location or how to get them to update automatically when the data validation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MyDataRng As Range, rng As Range, c As Range
    
    Set MyDataRng = Me.Range("B:B")
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, MyDataRng)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no updates in B
    
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
            c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 4).ClearContents 'clear A,C-G
        Else
            c.Offset(0, 3) = Now
            c.Offset(0, -1).Formula = "=I2"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thank you, this fixed my issue. I greatly appreciate it!!!